# Value retrieved from redux store not persisting on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux to store the values entered by the user but on refresh it is not persisting , what is redux doing here if it's purpose is to share the state across the app why is it not persisting the values? Apart from the solution please explain what is actually happening here. Here is my code for the component where I'm accessing the values. The value for `income` goes back to `0`.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import AccountBalanceIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountBalance';
import { addIncome } from '../../store/IncomeSlice';

function TotalIncome() {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  const month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const incomes = useSelector((state) => state.income.incomes);
  const income = incomes[month];
  const [spendingRatio, setSpendingRatio] = React.useState(0);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const incomeData = {
      income: parseFloat(income),
      month: month,
    };

    axios
      .post('http://localhost:8000/incomes', incomeData)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Income created:', response.data);
        dispatch(addIncome({ income: response.data.income, month: response.data.month }));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Failed to create income:', error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchExpenseIncomeRatio() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/expenses/sum');
        const totalExpenses = response.data.totalExpenses;
        const ratio = (totalExpenses / income) * 100;
        setSpendingRatio(ratio.toFixed(2));
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to calculate expense-income ratio:', error);
      }
    }

    fetchExpenseIncomeRatio();
  }, [income]);

  return (
    <div className='ml-20'>
      <h1 className='font-bold'>Enter your income for the current month</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type='text'
          value={income || ''}
          onChange={(e) => dispatch(addIncome({ income: parseFloat(e.target.value), month }))}
          placeholder='Enter Income'
          required
          className={`bg-transparent w-60 m-3 border-b-2 border-black`}
        />
        <button type='submit' className='bg-primary w-20 p-2 text-white text-sm rounded-md ml-2 hover:bg-white '>
          +
        </button>
      </form>
      <span className='m-1'>
        <AccountBalanceIcon />
      </span>{' '}
      {` Your Income for this month is ${parseInt(income)}`}
      <div>{`You have spent ${spendingRatio}% of your total income`}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and this is my slice for it

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  incomes: {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
    6: 0,
    7: 0,
    8: 0,
    9: 0,
    10: 0,
    11: 0,
    12: 0,
  },
};

const incomeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'income',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addIncome: (state, action) => {
      const { income, month } = action.payload;
      state.incomes[month] = income;
      console.log(state.incomes[month])
    },
  },
});

export const { addIncome } = incomeSlice.actions;

export default incomeSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh"? Does it mean clicking the browser refresh button?

Comment: Redux itself is only an in-memory app state management solution. If you reload the page, any state in memory is dumped. If you need to persist the state longer term then you'll need to do this yourself manually or integrate a library like [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "refresh" here?

Comment: yes , by refresh i meant reloading the page, i have for now stored the value in local storage but i don't know if that will be useful for storing many values

Answer (score 0):

As *Drew Reese* mentioned above redux hasn't ability to save values while page is being refreshed. Every time refresh is invoked redux set its default values (`initialState`). To overcome this you need [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist), this library store values in local storage ([or somewhere else if you want](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#storage-engines)) and keeps them during refreshes.
To set up redux-persist you need to add several changes:

1. add persist config and use it in root reducer (do it in file with `configureStore`):

   ```
   import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
   import { persistStore, persistReducer, FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER } from "redux-persist";
   import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

   const persistConfig = {
     key: "root",
     whitelist: ["income"], // keys under root which you want to persist, default is all
     blacklist: ["routing"], // keys under root which you don't want to persist, default is all
     storage: storage
   };


   export const store = configureStore({
     reducer: persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer), // wrap root reducer into persist
     // skip following setup if you use THUNK
     // for SAGA you need to add redux-persist actions to ignoredActions as they will cause serializable errors
     middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
     getDefaultMiddleware({
       thunk: false,
       serializableCheck: {
         ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER]
       }
     }).concat(middleware)
   });
   ```

   export const persistor = persistStore(store);

read about [whitelist and black list](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#blacklist--whitelist) and [how to specify them more deeply.](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#nested-persists)

2. wrap the whole app into `PersistGate`:

   ```
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
    import { store, persistor } from "./configureApp";

    const App = () => {
      ...your code

      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            {...your components}
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      )
    };
   ```